# How to show different attributes for different products?

Tags: magento, attributes

I am using Magento for my website. I have two or more groups of product. I want the front page of Group-A products to show Attributes A1, A2, A3...; the front page of Group-B products to show Attributes B1, B2, B3..., but not to show A1, A2, A3...How can I do it?

I learned that I can show a new attribute in front page by edit file view.phtml. However, I don't how to show different attributes for different products.

Comment: You are more likely to receive useful answers if you list the toolkits and technologies ("Magento"?) you are using as tags for your question. "attributes", on the other hand, is a very unspecific term that could be removed from the tags list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [different attribute sets](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-attribute-sets) and Group A products with Attribute Set 1 and Group B with attribute set 2

If you want to display attributes in view.phtml - it can be done multiple ways, for example create attribute Product Group with values A, B, C etc. then (not exact code, [read how to display attributes on product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559166/magento-how-to-get-attribute-values-used-in-products/))

```
<?php if ($_product->getProductGroup()=="A"): ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeA1() ?>
<?php elseif ($_product->getProductGroup()=="B"): ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeB1() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```